# Why is my RNN model outputting the error: 'Input 0 of layer is incompatible with the layer'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have issue in my RNN model. The error is:

```
Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 90, 3), found shape=(None, 3).
```

I still don't know how to solve this.

I tried to changing the dimension and ask ChatGPT but still haven't found the solution about the error. Here is my dataset:

[image]

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alwanrahmanas/DataPDBHargaBerlaku2000-2023/main/Lag%20PDB.csv

Here is my code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U_f-gVnW_LYyIyelnnDBrT1BzQ7PCsde?usp=sharing

```
# Define the train-test split ratio
train_ratio = 0.90

# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_size = int(len(p) * train_ratio)
train, test = p[:train_size], p[train_size:]

# Define the sequence length (number of time steps to look back)
sequence_length = 10

#Define input dim
input_dim = 3

vx =['PDBTriwulan-1','PDBTriwulan-2','PDBTriwulan-3']
vy =['PDB']

X_train = train[vx]
y_train = train[vy]

X_test = test[vx]
y_test = test[vy]

model = Sequential()

model.add(SimpleRNN(units=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(90, 3), return_sequences = True))

adam = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=30) ##at this chunk, error happened
```

Comment: Please read the stackoverflow article on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot run your code when you provide your data as a screenshot. Also you left out important parts of the code, e.g. how you read the input data. One question for clarification: Have you tried to print the output of `train` and `test` after you slice them with `train, test = p[:train_size], p[train_size:]` ?

Comment: i did put the link of the code sir

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your expected dimensions are for input and output data.

However, according to the docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SimpleRNN) you can call SimpleRNN without any shape information, so you can get ride of your error... if this is what you want, I don't know, as I have no idea of your desired length of tokens that you want to use for predictions.

```
# here batch size is 32 (=32 seperate predictions)
# Each prediction is based on 10 timesteps [in your case also 10]
# Each timestep has 8 datapoints [in your case: 3]
inputs = np.random.random([32, 10, 8]).astype(np.float32)

# output has 4 datapoints [in your case 1 (???)]
simple_rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(4)

# The output has shape `[32, 4]`. [in your case [32 (batch), 1]]
output = simple_rnn(inputs)
```

good luck